# Running count with no origin

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log of TIMESTAMPS when users LOGIN or LOGOUT of a machine.

I'd like to create a stepped graph showing users concurrently in the LOGIN state throughout the day.

One idea I had to accomplish this was to select the TIMESTAMP alongside this:.

```
select
  TIMESTAMP,
  case STATUS 
    when LOGIN then +1
    when LOGOUT then -1
  end as "MOVEMENT"
from
  TABLE
```

Then do a running total on movement, which would return a table of concurrent users and TIMESTAMP.

The problem I'm having is that I can't run this query from the beginning of time, and so I need some sort of start date.  But I don't know how I can calculate how many users there were at the cutoff.  So if I don't pick a point in time where there were zero users online, or start the running total with the number of users online, then I have no way of calculating this.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating the number of users at the cutoff is actually easy.  The logic for the query is just to count the number of logins and logouts since the beginning of time:

```
select sum(case status when LOGIN then 1 when LOGOUT then -1 end) as NumUsers
from table
where timestamp <= @timestampcutoff;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure why I was so squeamish about simply calculating it.  Now I just need to figure out how to do a running sum in 2008r2.

Comment: @user38858 . . . You can use a correlated subquery.  Or, as I often do, just copy the data in Excel and do the sum there.